# Express how to pass .json into res.render

Tags: javascript, json, express, object

How can I pass an object array like this:

```
var DataArray = [
{"type": "c#", "script":"csharp script"},
{"type": "javascript", "script":"javascript script"},
{"type": "html", "script":"html script"}
]
```

Into res.render

```
res.render('index.ejs');
```

I've tried using the options, but as far as I know that only accepts a string value and I wasn't able to get it working (I received the default [object Object] value)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If my answer was correct, please accept it. Otherwise, please comment to let me know if it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the express [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.render) docs, you can pass `locals` as the second argument to `render`. For templating engines, packages that would render html after inserting provided variables, those variables were often called *locals*.

```js
// pass a local variable to the view
res.render('user', { name: 'Tobi' }, function (err, html) {
  // ...
})
```